# jquery.scrollTo not working depending on how I call it

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have an index.html file where I create the following variable like so:

```
target = $('#portfolio23-inline1 div.inline-cont');
```

Then, in my site.js file, I do a bunch of things and that's from where I call the function like so:

```
target.scrollTo('#' + id, {duration:700,axis:"y",offset:0});
```

This way, it works

But if I want to to it the folowing way, it doesn't:

```
$('#portfolio23-inline1 div.inline-cont').scrollTo('#' + id, {duration:700,axis:"y",offset:0});
```

I'd like to do it this way as I want to dynamically change the portfolio23-inline1 id that can be portfolio26-inline1 etc depending on the id variable value. I'd like something like:

```
$('#portfolio' + id + '-inline1 div.inline-cont').scrollTo('#' + id, {duration:700,axis:"y",offset:0});
```

Does somebody have an idea of what's going wrong with what I'm coding ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `target = $('#portfolio23-inline' + id + ' div.inline-cont');`

Comment: @Kinder any error in your console?

Comment: @Felipe as soon as I try to set the target value in my js file, the scroll doesn't work...

Comment: @Yogesh no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
$(window).scrollTo( 
    $('#portfolio' + id + '-inline1 div.inline-cont'), 
    { duration:700, axis:"y", offset:0 }
);
```

Comment: Hi there,
I tried that but it doesn't work since the <div> I want to scroll into is in a popup window called with fancybox.

Comment: I did a few more tests like following. If I initialize my target in the index.html like so:
`target = $('#cueDiv_23');`
the scroll works
but if I intialize it in the site.js with the exacte same way,
`target = $('#cueDiv_23');` 
it doesn't work !
I didn't even try to set the number of the div dynamically, really putting the same line of code, and for some reason, it won't work.
If I print the value of target in the console, the result is the same on both situations:
**[div#cueDiv_23.inline-cont, context: document, selector: "#cueDiv_23"]**
Other than that, no error in the console

Comment: @Kinder In that case, instead of `$(window)`, try using the FancyBox container, `$('#fancybox-content')` IIRC. You may need to initialize the `scrollTo` in the `onComplete` callback for FancyBox.

Comment: Well I have put the call in the `afterShow` function of FancyBox but with no luck. the #cueDiv_23 container is actually the fancybox one.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is having a video playing, and the description container below it scrolls to the right text according to the created cues.
Works here:[link](http://www.sebastien-muller.com/V8/index.html)
But not here:[link](http://www.sebastien-muller.com/V8/index.php)
The only difference is that for the php version, I dynamically replace the target value in the `afterShow` function of Fancybox instead of keeping the one initialized in index

Comment: On the 1st link you need to scroll down to the Portfolio section and click on the eye icon of the top right image, for the second link, click on the eye icon of the biggest image